# How to colspan the same entries in a table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

my query in mysql returns my table that looks like this

```
contract_ID     warehouse     seller     name    quantity
1                ware1         John       A        50
1                ware1         John       B        30
1                ware1         John       C        10
2                ware1         Peter      A        30
2                ware1         Peter      D        55
2                ware1         Peter      E        25
```

How do I make it so that the entries don't repeat themselves, but are rather merged? So I would have the '1' long to cover A, B and C and '2' would cover A, D and E kind of like colspan.

```
contract_ID     warehouse     seller     name    quantity
                                          A        50
1                ware1         John       B        30
                                          C        10
                                          A        30
2                ware1         Peter      D        55
                                          E        25
```

I don't know if I can use colspan in some way, because I don't know how many IDs will be the same. Because right now I have a simple table in a foreach cycle where every row has its own entry.

Comment: If you are looking for mysql solution then mysql is not meant for this, you have to use the application layer to handle it.

Comment: I don't have experience with this problem, so I have no idea if it is better to do with mysql, or in php later. How could I achieve it later in php then? Or maybe in javascript?